# Angular Universal and firebase

Tags: angular

I am developing a website with angular 4.

I am implementing angular universal and hosting in firebase.
If I refresh the page or go to the page manually, I get this error:

> **Error**: could not handle the request
>   I tried putting "destination": "/index.html" in the rewrites

and I get this error when I try to deploy.

> **Error**: HTTP Error: 400, hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from [subschema 0],[subschema 1]

I also get the same error if I use "Firebase serve".

It works fine if I refresh or type the page manually using "ng serve".

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you added to your firebase.json file? It should have a rewrite to the function that executes the serverside-rendering. The functions folder should also not have an index.html file.

Comment: I followed David East's video on youtube. Everything works except when you have a multiple pages website. If you need to go to the page manually or just refresh the page, it does not work. Here is what I have in firebase.json

{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "ssrapp"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: I believe your rewrites section should look like this: "rewrites": [{"source": "**", "function": "ssrapp"}]. You just forgot the double **.

Comment: I do have the double asterisks. Probably I erased one when I posted the comment. Sorry. I do have the double asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow [David East's Guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxCu5TEmxXE) as well but was unsuccessful at a successful deploy.  I found an alternate way to successfully deploy an Angular 5 Universal app to Firebase, and I explain how I did it step-by-step in my github repo: https://github.com/Stanza987/angular-universal-firebase.

The bottom line is using Cloud Functions is rather clunky.  On the plus side, Angular CLI v1.6 now has native Universal support so you can just generate most of the files with `ng generate universal universal` with minimal editing.  The Firebase side, sadly, is much more complex.